# Do lights in a circuit have to be grounded for the whole circuit to be grounded?

Tags: receptacle, grounding, ground

I have a circuit in my old house (built 1918), it’s gone through many remodels during its lifespan and multiple owners.

This one circuit has no grounded outlets, so I had a look behind the outlet to see what the story was. It appears that all these outlets have copper wires back there, so I picked up some grounded outlets and hooked up the copper wires to the ground not - all to no avail. Now my outlets show “open ground”.

I can’t see any other outlets on this circuit, and it appears everything is fine. The only thing relatively near these outlets are two lights (not a traditional light). They are on the wall, and use a twist/click mechanism to turn on and off. Would these also need to be grounded in order for the whole circuit to be correct?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to rectify the open ground issue? No, the lights don't need to be grounded for that. You need a grounding conductor connecting back to the panel. Chances are you have some 14/2 with ground attached to  and extending a circuit initially wired with 14/2 _without_ ground. The only good solution is to re-run that upstream segment with modern cable.

Comment: @isherwood I am asking how to fix that, yes. It’s very odd, everything else in the house with the new cabling (looks to have been installed at the same time) is grounded correctly.

Comment: Do you know which line it is on the box (I'll assume breakers)? Is there a ground wire there?

Comment: @ben, I believe there’s a ground wire there - yep. That’s why I’m confused. Everywhere else in the house is grounded that’s why I’m unsure what’s actually up. But yes, I do know which breaker it is, is there a simple way to check if that breaker is grounded?

Comment: The breaker wouldn't be grounded, the circuit would but you already checked that. As mentioned by @isherwood, it seems that some part of the circuit between that plug and the breaker box either doesn't have a ground, or just isn't connected. All you can really do is check the whole thing, which requires that you know where that line is run and to which breaker. What you could do is connect something like a lamp and turn off one breaker at a time until it goes out, then look at that line and see if the ground is connected.

Comment: @Ben, on closer inspection of my breaker panel. It doesn’t look like that breaker has any ground at all (https://imgur.com/a/0CQJxLO) - see image with red mark on the breaker that controls that circuit (amongst others).

Comment: Grounds don't go to the breaker. Neither do neutrals in most cases. The red wire is a little odd. Follow the red wire back to the cable where it enters the box and note the black white and bare wires which join it in the cable. Follow each of those and tell me where they go. I am also interested in the black.

Comment: @Harper, it's a little tricky to follow. The red cable flows through and into a thicker cable (containing the hot and neutral), and then into a box where it is spliced. The hot cable is spliced with a hot wire that has its neutral and ground wires cut. The neutral is spliced with 2 neutrals that both have its hot and grounds cut. I am hoping to follow the spliced cables today and see if they come together again at some point. I have a poorly drawn diagram here (https://imgur.com/a/9ATXHoF).

Comment: The Red wire had better be the Hot - it's the one on the breaker, the Neutral and Ground shouldn't be on the breaker. Once you get to the point where you know which Neutral and Ground that red wire is associated with, where are _they_ connected _inside_ the breaker box? That's the key bit of info @Harper is looking for. If the ground in that NM housing isn't connected to anything in the box, that's why you've got an open Ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your drawing correctly, 3 possibilities (all incorrect under current code) may have existed in the past:

1. They may have had a 220v line at one time split between 2 cables.
2. They had 2 cables but a wire got cut or broken so they used a wire from each of the cables to build a circuit.
3. They paralleled wires from 2 cables for higher current capacity.

I have found all 3 of these in my own 1929 house.

Regardless of which case it is, there's a break in the ground between the breaker panel and the outlet. You'll have to trace the circuit to find the break and correct it.  As Isherwood said, your best solution is to rewire that circuit with a single new grounded cable from the panel out.